# Horizontal ListBox multiple lines (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to implement a horizontal ListBox, with multiple lines.

Using WrapPanel:

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

I get the following result:

[image]

But I am looking for this result:

[image]

How can I implement this?

Comment: Have you tried a `UniformGrid` instead of a `StackPanel`?

Comment: @SomeBody Yes, but with UniformGrid I couldn't define the MinWidth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments, I made a [`UniformGrid`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/uniformgrid) which adjusts the number of rows/columns, whenever the window is resized.

**MainWindow.xaml:**

```
<Grid x:Name="Container">
    <ListBox HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
          <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid x:Name="ItemsGrid" Loaded="ItemsGrid_Loaded" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

The names and events are important. They are used for adjusting the columns/rows in the code file.

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private UniformGrid itemsGrid;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ItemsGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Set reference and adjust columns/rows once the UniformGrid is loaded.
        itemsGrid = sender as UniformGrid;
        ((UniformGrid)sender).Columns = (int)(Container.ActualWidth / 250);
        ((UniformGrid)sender).Rows = (int)(Container.ActualHeight / 75);
    }

    private void Window_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Adjust number of columns/rows whenevner the window is resized.
        if (itemsGrid != null)
        {
            itemsGrid.Columns = (int)(Container.ActualWidth / 250);
            itemsGrid.Rows = (int)(Container.ActualHeight / 75);
        }
    }
}
```

This could definitely be cleaned up a bit, but it seems to do the job. There might be more elegant solutions, but I couldn't find any...

Comment: I didn't do it as you indicated, because I want the number of columns to automatically adjust to the Width of the ListBox.

Comment: I hope it is understood with this image: https://i.imgur.com/pV8ZLAw.png

Comment: Thank you, I implemented your idea, and that is what I was looking for. The only problem I have when using UniformGrid is that by changing the vertical size of the window, the height of each item changes, and bug the vertical scrollbar.